# How can I force the amdgpu module to load after other modules?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel

I am trying to set up my dual GPU system for VFIO Passthrough (so my 2nd GPU can be used fully by a virtual machine).  In order to do this I need to make sure that the 2nd GPU is not grabbed by the `amdgpu` driver, and is instead grabbed by either `pci-stub` or `xen-pciback`.

Unfortunately, my system with 4.13.4 kernel (from Ukuu) is causing the `amdgpu` module to be loaded too early, grabbing both GPUs.  I have tried blacklisting the `amdgpu` module and that works but it requires me to manually `modprobe amdgpu` after login to load the `amdgpu` driver so I can use my first GPU.

The only way I could find to automate loading the `amdgpu` is by adding the modprobe command to `/etc/rc.local` but that generally doesn't get executed until 10-20 seconds after I am presented with an X login prompt (causing me to have to login twice if I forget to wait till the modprobe finishes).

Is there any way to reliably make the `amdgpu` driver load after other modules?

*Edit:* It appears I can do this if I blacklist the `amdgpu` module, rebuild `initramfs`, then remove the `amdgpu` blacklist without updating `initramfs`.  This causes the modules to load in the order specified and everything work.  Unfortunately, this is only a temporary fix :-/.

Comment: Did you delete your previous question and post this instead?

Comment: Yes, as this is more direct to what I've learned the true issue is.  The other question (about the splash screen display) is actually tangental to my true issue.

Comment: Yeah, looking around it seems the only solution people have found is to blacklist and manually `modprobe`... maybe someone will put a bounty on this question though, because there has to be a better way. [There are plenty of people with the same issue](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2015-October/282928.html)

Comment: The workaround in the edit worked for me too. Much appreciate this being up here as I'd experimented a bit with other methods fruitlessly :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [softdep command for modprobe](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/modprobe.conf.5.html) to make sure vfio-pci loads before amdgpu. See example below:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/vfio-pci.conf
options vfio-pci ids=1002:xxxx
softdep amdgpu pre: vfio-pci
```

With this it should be necessary either to have eg a `pci-stub.ids` on the grub cmdline in `/etc/default/grub`